# Linux USB video capture issues

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, v4l2

I purchased the Hauppauge USB-Live 2 capture device because several recent Amazon reviews suggest it should work with modern Linux kernels.

When I plug it into my Raspberry Pi 4 running the latest version of Raspbian Buster it does seems to be successfully recognized:

- Here's is the dmesg output: https://pastebin.com/kybfrpJH
- v4l2-ctl --all shows this: https://pastebin.com/2237MNX1

Unfortunately when I try to run ffmpeg / ffplay to capture video from a running VHS source it shows 0 bits of input data at all coming in (report here: https://pastebin.com/TAurevCA). I also tried to capture a frame with "v4l2-ctl --device /dev/video0 --stream-mmap --stream-to=frame.raw --stream-count=1" as well as "vlc v4l2:///dev/video0" and neither contains data

I confirmed with Hauppauge tech support by email that the unit has been tested with the Rpi 4 and should work. A couple of the fixes I've tried with no luck:

- Many reboots
- Moving the device to the various USB 2 and USB 3 ports
- I made sure to set vl42 to NTSC to match my source
- Running ffmpeg with sudo in case it was a permissions issue for /dev/video0 (also tried chmod -R 777 /dev/video0)
- Replaced firmware with the version I found at this manufacturer link - https://www.hauppauge.de/pctv-faq/doku.php?id=en:linux:usb-live2-how-to (I believe RPi already had this installed because the old file size was exactly the same as the new file)
- Emailed tech support - they indicated that the device has been tested to work on the Rpi 4 and were otherwise not helpful
- Ordered another identical device off of Amazon to try in case it was a faulty unit - same result
- I know my VCR/connections works fine because a similar capture device works fine with the exact same setup

Any thoughts on what else to try here? I also tried the unit on my Mac with Ubuntu 18.04.3 running off of a live USB and the same result so I’m thinking maybe I’m missing something basic?

Also just in case it's useful info to anyone else here is some info about other USB capture devices that I've tried with the Raspberry Pi 4:

(1) I can confirm that this cheaper device works pretty well on the Pi 4
DIGITNOW USB 2.0 Audio/Video Converter - Digitize and Edit Video from Any Analog Source Including VCR, VHS, DVD
https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B06XJKSJZ8/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

The driver shows as "uvcvideo" rather than cx231xx
(The quality is just passable so I'm trying to see if I can do better - this one only outputs full resolution in MJPEG which is already compressed)

(2) Do NOT waste your money on this one, the image jumps around and is completely unusable:
UVC Usb2.0 Video Capture Card, Compatible Window/Linux
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00RMYWGWC/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_i_P-RpEb9BRFMNR](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00RMYWGWC)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you tried this, but to get my Live 2 to capture with ffmpeg, I had to:

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 -s ntsc at every boot
```

So I added it to `crontab` with

```
@reboot v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 -s ntsc
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit 1: I found out why these devices doesn't work properly. The problem is if you don't initialize the companion audio device, they will not return video frames. You don't need to read all audio frames, but you need to initialize and read the first frame, others can be ignored. That's why the proposed mencoder command works, because it initializes the audio too.

I was able to capture using mencoder, so here is a solution:

Try this command:

```
mencoder \
-v -noskip \
tv:///0 \
-tv norm=NTSC\
:device=/dev/video0\
:driver=v4l2\
:outfmt=i420\
:width=720:height=480\
:fps=29.97\
:alsa\
:adevice=hw.0,0\
:amode=1\
:buffersize=200 \
-ffourcc divx \
-oac mp3lame \
-lameopts cbr:preset=128 \
-ovc lavc \
-lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4\
:vbitrate=1400\
:threads=2\
:autoaspect \
-vf dsize=4/3 \
-vf-add scale \
-vf-add kerndeint=10:0:0:1:1 \
-vf-add softskip,harddup \
-endpos 02:10:00 \
-o ~/usblive2.avi
```

This will create a file named usblive2.avi on your home folder.